# Help undestanding compactness with convergent subsequences

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

One way to define compactness in metric spaces is to note that in compact metric space each sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Understanding compactness is difficult for me from this perspective. Let's take the set of real numbers as an example. Say my sequence is something like $(1,2,3,...)$ that isn't convergent. But why can't I pick, say the subsequence $(1,1,1,...)$, i.e. a sequence that is constant, and so convergent? And similarly for every possible sequence in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1,1,1,\dots)$ is *not* a subsequence of $(1,2,3,\dots)$.

If you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$, then a subsequence of that is any sequence $$a_{i_1},a_{i_2},a_{i_3},\dots$$
where $i_1,i_2,i_3,\dots$ are some natural numbers such that $$i_1<i_2<i_3<\dots.$$

This means that for the sequence $(1,2,3,\dots)$, you can take $i_1=1$ so the first element of the subsequence will be $1$, but you cannot take $i_2=1$ because $i_2$ must be *larger* than $i_1$.

---

The subsequence must be a "proper" subsequence, meaning you can only take each element of the original sequence one (or zero) times.

Comment: This is it, thank you! I had forgotten there was a strict inequality between the indices. So the subsequences are always "evolving to the same direction" with the original sequence for certain. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer is indeed all you need, consider upvoting and accepting it so the question will not be listed as unanswered...

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. I think there is a timelimit in how fast can one accept an answer :)